# Does a creature possessed by intellect devourer have blindsight?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The intellect devourer's feature Body Thief says the following:

> While inside a creature, the intellect devourer has total cover against attacks and other effects originating outside its host. The intellect devourer retains its Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores, as well as its understanding of Deep Speech, its telepathy, and **its traits**. It otherwise adopts the target’s statistics.

Does it retain its 60ft blindsight and immunity to the blinded condition while inside the creature?

Answer (score 5):

### No, because blindsight is part of the "stat block," not the "traits" of the monster description

While the intellect devourer retains its traits, blindsight is not a trait in the terminology of 5e, *per se*.  This is how we know:

The "stat block" is introduced on p. 6 of the MM and its elements detailed on pp. 6-9.  Note that the last element of the "stat block" is the challenge rating. Then on p. 10, the next section of the monster description template is introduced:

> **Special Traits**
> Special traits (which appear after a monster's challenge rating but before any actions or reactions)...

This means the **intellect devourer** has only one "trait," which is:

> **Detect Sentience.** The intellect devourer can sense the presence and location of any creature with 300 feet of it that has Intelligence of 3 or higher...

So it retains *that* feature, but not its blindsight.

Comment: At least for me, this is where it became confusing (and, maybe, not having the mm is the problem). You cited Special Traits. This, for me, would mean that there are normal, non, special traits. If that were the case, that there are normal traits, the wording in the Body Thief would include both, special and non special. IDK if OP is confused because of that fact. I'm sure I am.

Comment: @Chepelink I see. The RAW  does use "traits" as a kind of shorthand to refer to these.  I think this happens in the texts because overall there are two kinds of traits that I'm aware of: "racial traits" for races and "special traits" for monsters.  Generically, they are all "traits."